# How does an indexing set work?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $\Omega$ be an indexing set such that $U_{\alpha}$ is a subspace of V for every $\alpha \in \Omega$, and let $I$ denote their intersection, that is $I = \bigcap_{\alpha \in \Omega}U_{\alpha}$.

This is the beginning of a proof to show that a collection of subspaces and their intersections is also a subspace. However, I need some assistance in my understanding.

What exactly is the purpose of the indexing set? Why does every $\alpha$ (amount of subspaces in the collection) need to be apart of some arbitrary set?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could write the set of subspaces that we want to intersect as $$\{A,B,C,\ldots,\}$$ but we eventually run out of letters.

We could instead write the set of subspaces that we want to intersect as $$\{A_i\}_{i=1}^n=\{A_1,A_2,\ldots,A_n\}$$ or $$\{A_i\}_{i \geq 1}=\{A_1,A_2,\ldots\}$$ but these describe only finite or countable sets.  (Here, we already have indexing sets $I=\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ and $I=\{1,2,\ldots\}$, respectively, but we don't explicitly use them.)

If we want to intersect uncountably many subspaces, then we need to index them by a set with cardinality that is uncountable.

Comment: Very helpful. Thank you.